# Images from json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, scripting

I have following json data from a web api:

```
 [{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/download (1).jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/download (2).jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/download.jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/images (1).jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/images (2).jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/images (3).jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/images (4).jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/images (5).jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/images (6).jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/images (7).jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/images.jpg"},{"FileName":"D:\\StuckUpTask\\Insta\\Insta\\Images\\/island1.jpg"}]
```

Is it possible an angualar js code to call this json result and show the pictures as thumbnail?

Comment: How will angular know where to take the pictures from? The json data just gives the filename. you will also need their location.

Comment: I updated the question, will this work? see the json data?

Answer (score 0):

No. The only data you have is about the file names in the machine that you got the JSON array from (maybe not even that), but to have access to those images, you would need to have the exact url to those images and also permission to view them.

Comment: I updated the question, will this work? see the json data?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is still no. That is the path of the image within the machine in which it is located. But to have access to that image from another machine you must have the URLs for those images to able to locate them. But maybe it would be useful to tell us more precisely what you are trying to do.